# How does compiler know if there are 'more tokens' unless it has already read the next token?

Tags: python, compiler-construction, tokenize

I'm working through 'nandtotetris' and in chapter 10 you make a tokenizer for a compiler.  The book advises writing a hasMoreTokens routine and using an advance routine to get next token(if hasMoreTokens returns true) and a tokenType routine etc.  I'm using python and can read by line and by character. I can get the tokens by reading character by character but I'm only sure of it after I've actually read the token and therefore already know what the tokenType will return anyway..?  Can anyone explain the rationale of the books advice?

Thanks. and the book is here:  http://www.cs.huji.ac.il/course/2002/nand2tet/docs/ch_10_compiler_I.pdf    on page 12.

Had thought of splitting up into substrings each of which has no whitespace but this doesn't seem right because you still have to go back and handle things like 'mary=2*(frank-1)' etc

Comment: Depends to an extent what `hasMoreTokens` is supposed to do in the event that the following data is invalid as a token. If it's allowed to return true, and if you're reading character-by-character, then in principle you only have to know that there is another character in order to return from `hasMoreTokens`. Seeing a quote is enough to say there's another token, you could delay reading the entire 25MB string literal until the parser asks for it :-) However I don't know what this particular text is expecting so I'm not sure this is an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to read through that entire PDF (though I did skim it), but I think I can guess what the intent is.

The parsing process is divided logically into a tokenizer (aka lexical analyzer, aka lexer) and a parser. The tokenizer inspects the source code character by character and returns tokens. The parser reads a stream of tokens and returns parsed data structures.

The tokenizer can know if there is another token before the parser knows it. The `hasMoreTokens` routine can read ahead and find out if there are more tokens available or not. In practice, a good way to do it is to have your tokenizer only look at each character once if possible.

I would probably have it keep track of two tokens at a time, the last two that were read. The first of these is the "current" token from the parser's perspective, and the second is the "next" token. The `hasMoreTokens` routine then tells the parser what the second of this pair is currently. If the tokenizer always knows what the next token will be, then it can always answer the question of whether there is another token available.

Comment: Sounds right except the book also advises to use tokenizer first and then go on to parsing the output...

Comment: You could do it that way but there's not really much advantage to it. Conceptually, the tokenizer reads a stream of characters and and produces a stream of tokens, then the parser reads the stream of tokens and produces a tree structure. In reality, though, the tokenizing and parsing operations normally alternate. The tokenizer is usually just a function that the parser calls whenever it needs another token. If you find it easier, though, parse all the tokens first.